# Vertices in edit mode being mirrored WITHOUT mirror modifier

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, mirror

I have no clue how I did it (maybe while blindly following a tutorial), but somehow my head object is mirroring vertices - without a mirror modifier.

Notice the difference in the two images. The top image is before I moved a vertex on the right, the bottom image is showing it mirrored.
[image: model in edit mode]

[image: actions mirrored with no modifier]

I tried loading an earlier version of the model before I'd parented the armature to the mesh with automatic weights, and the head didn't have this problem. But I tested it and it doesn't seem to be the armature's fault that this is happening.

Why is this happening? How do I remove the mirror effect? I need to fix this so I can rig asymmetrical emotions into the face.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you have the [X-mirror](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh_options.html#x-mirror) option on.

Open up the tool shelf <kbd>T</kbd> switch to the *Option* tab and uncheck the *X Mirror* checkbox.

[image: Mesh options in the tool shelf]