# Real time symmetry modeling

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror

In maya there a way to move vertices or whatever in symmetry without using a modifier. That is usefull in making changes after a model with its uvs for example are already made and you want to tweek things a bit. But using the mirror modifier to do such thing will destroy the uvs of half the model.
Its also pretty fast and handy.

Is there a way to do that in blender?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use X-Mirror. It only works on the X-axis but doesn't require a mirror modifier. While transforming and other simple operation work well, more complex operations like deleting or disolving may not be mirrored correctly.

From [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/95011/30849):

> Sounds like you [want] the [X-mirror](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh_options.html#x-mirror) option.
>
> Open up the tool shelf <kbd>T</kbd> switch to the *Option* tab and
>   [check] the *X Mirror* checkbox.
>
> [image: Mesh options in the tool shelf]

Comment: Thats not a bad option. Though there is not a Y-mirror or a Z-mirror.
You can't mirror knife tool, edge loop tool and i think you can only select in symmetry with this option.